# Emulating a Chromecast on a Windows desktop

Tags: windows-media-player, kodi, dlna, upnp, chromecast

I am aware of the settings that allow Windows Media Player to become a DLNA receiver and the ability enable UPnP on Kodi (which is my current setup).

What I would like to do is have the native support that Android provides when casting to (from within an app, i.e. YouTube) to something like a Chromecast or a cast enabled TV.

Is there any way to achieve this currently?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cast is a proprietary technology, much like Apple AirPlay.

Luckily, there’s [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/). It claims to serve as an endpoint for:

- Miracast
- Apple AirPlay, including FullHD support
- Google Cast

It’s not free though. At the time of writing this answer, a regular end-user license is 13,99 € (excl. VAT).

(Miracast requires a compatible WiFi adapter with compatible drivers [NDIS 6.4+].)

I haven’t used the software, so I cannot say if it works well.